# Why clear both do not work for right in css?

Tags: html, css, css-float

My code is here, I set the `div2`'s `clear:both` in my stylesheet, but the div3 still float next to it:

```css
#div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

#div2 {
  width: 20em;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: seagreen;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

#div3 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 3cm;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  div1
</div>

<div id="div2">
  div2
</div>

<div id="div3">
  div3
</div>
```

The effect of the float:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

You see the div3 is next to div2, but my div2 is clear both, why get that？
I have test in firefox and safari, no difference.

Comment: you are using `float: left;` with `clear: both;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clear` means an element won't bubble up beside a *previous* floating element.

Since *div2* is `clear: both`, it doesn't move up beside *div1*.

Since *div2* is `float: left`, it moves to the left and *div3* bubbles up beside it.

*div3* doesn't have `clear` so nothing is stopping it from bubbling up.

Answer (score 0):

you can add clear to div3 as well.